# How do I uninstall Java 11 to be able to install Java 8 for Android Studio?

Tags: java, jdk, android-studio

I tried to install Android Studio but it gave me several problems.
Among them is that they told me that it need Java 8 while on my PC Java 11 is installed.
When I run `java -version`, the result is the following:

```
java version "11.0.2" 2018-10-16 LTS Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment
18.9 (build 11.0.2 + 7-LTS) Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2 + 7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I see that java is in `/usr/bin`, in fact there are several java folder/files:

```
java, javac, javadoc, javafxpackager, javah, javap, javapackager, javaws
```

How should I remove java in order to install Java 8 and be able to install Android Studio correctly?

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/java`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 feb 5 18:56 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 feb 16 23:33 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java
```

I have tried several commands, but the problem is that I do not know exactly how to install it. 
On the other hand, when I search for Java in "UBUNTU SOFTWARE", Java does not appear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java` which is in turn is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java`. From this, it seems that you've downloaded and configured Oracle's Java 11. Moreover JDK doesn't appear as an standalone app in Ubuntu Software.

To get rid of that Java and install Java 8 (OpenJDK):

- Remove the Oracle's Java folder:

  ```
  sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
  ```
- Install OpenJDK 8 from APT:

  ```
  sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
  ```
- Confirm Java version using:

  ```
  java -version
  ```

Answer (score 25):

No need to uninstall your other java version(s) that's already installed on your machine.
Whenever required, you can conveniently use the utility 'update-alternatives' to choose the Java runtime that you wish to activate. It will automagically update the required symbolic links.

You just need to run the below command, and select the version of your choice. That's all!

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: This only lets you choose from Java versions you previously installed. For example my machine lets me choose between Java 8 Auto and Java 8 Manual. None of the other Java versions appear on the list.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The program might require a specific version of java to run. You probably have to download openjdk 8 from the java website or by using the command-line, the link with provide instructions on how to do so.
https://openjdk.java.net/install/ 
deleting the previous version of java shouldn't be necessary

Comment: my apologies if this doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, do not help me. Besides should read  [how to ask a question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)and so give some explanation. Just put a link, if that link is broken, the answer does not help.
Thank you

Comment: the link works perfectly fine